# Pfsense open port to internet connection

Tags: iptables, pfsense

I switched from Ubuntu to pfsense. Which ports and how to open the internet to work?
If I do `any` (the last rule works) but that's not what I want. i just want to open (53,80,443)

**Pfsense**
[image]

**Ubuntu iptables**
I had these ports open on ubuntu and the internet was working (80,53,443)

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/min --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I changed from source to destination port. Now it is working.